# case asterisk (an actual astrisk) in bash's case in?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a case "$2" in and I need to check if $2 is equal to an asterisk "*" but since asterisk is the case default, how can I?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just escape it:

```
\*) commands;;
```

or

```
'*') commands;;
```